# Owl-carousel offset at begin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am using the owlCarousel plugin and I want it to have an offset at the beginning and then go normal as the carousel is going over it.

An example of this is [Kaw](https://www.kaw.nl/)

This is my configuration for the carousel:

```
$(".owl-carousel.carousel-autoplay").owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    autoPlay: 5000,
    pagination: false, 
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: false,
});
```

Comment: Post your effort when ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [stagePadding](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html)

```
stagePadding: Number
```

Usage

```
$(".owl-carousel.carousel-autoplay").owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    autoPlay: 5000,
    pagination: false, 
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: false,
    stagePadding: 10 //padding in pixels
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your code but you can use this css, or something similar to that:

```
.owl-stage-outer .owl-stage item:first-child {padding-left: 11%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same as in the demo, set the x-offset of translate3d on the swiper-wrapper:

```
    .swiper-wrapper { transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d({offset}px, 0px, 0px); }
```

If you want to keep the offset when the carousel moves, set offset on the parent container:

```
.owl-carousel { margin-left: {offset}px; }
```

Comment: This is not an solution becaus the plugin wil overwrite it when the carousel moves.

Comment: I thought that was the intention, because the example also does that. As Lenny86 stated in his answer, set the offset on the container div.

Answer (score 0):

They used the  [`transform property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and `translate3d()` function. You could also offset the container div with `translateX(1200px, 0, 0)`